# Selenium - Wait until element is NOT visible

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In the code below, I attempt to wait until an element is visible:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("processing")));
```

Is it possible to tell driver to wait until that element is NOT visible?

Answer (score 47):

Yes, it's possible with method `invisibilityOfElementLocated`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Comment: One thing that sucks about this is that you need to wait for the duration of the implicit wait.  Annoying unexpected implementation. (Selenium 2.48.2)

Comment: @Coops, this is now also available for C# as of 2017.

Comment: Bad that 'ExpectedConditions' now is obsolete and will be removed in future releases.

Answer (score 13):

The following  should wait until the element is no longer displayed i.e. not visible (or time out after 10 seconds)

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(driver => !driver.FindElement(By.Id("processing")).Displayed);
```

It will throw an exception if an element cannot be found with the id `processing`.

Comment: That is the problem, it thrown an exception:

Comment: It will throw an exception.  TDHM has correct answer.

Comment: This looks like it should work, because it tries to check if an element is NOT displayed, with the ! in front. However it fails because this bit:

driver.FindElement(By.Id("whatever")).Displayed) will NOT be found (because something may be obscuring it), so it doesn't matter if you have an ! in front. It fails. The error I get is:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"whatever element you checked for"}

In my case the comment below worked:

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("my element")));

Answer (score 7):

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("processing")));
```

The idea is to wait until element is not visible. First line sets wait time that element has to disappear; here it's 10 seconds. Second line uses selenium to check if condition "invisibilityofElementLocated" is met. Element is found by its id as in topic case, that is `id="processing"`. If element doesn't disappear in the requested period of time, a Timeout exception will be raised and the test will fail.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Of course. I thought that it's self explainable, my bad.
Topic was: Wait until element not Visible.
First line sets wait time that element has to disappear, here it's 10 seconds.
Second line uses selenium that checks if condition "invisibilityofElementLocated" is met. Element is found by it's id as in topic case, that is id="processsing"
If element won't disappear in requested period of time, Timeout exception will be raised and test will fail.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020, ExpectedConditions is deprecated in .NET.

For some reason, I was not able to make IgnoreExceptionTypes work.

The only solution that worked for me was the one proposed by Anoop.  One thing I like about his solution is it returns as soon as the element becomes invisible.

I generalized his solution a bit as follows:

```
//returns as soon as element is not visible, or throws WebDriverTimeoutException
protected void WaitUntilElementNotVisible(By searchElementBy, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds))
                    .Until(drv => !IsElementVisible(searchElementBy));
}

private bool IsElementVisible(By searchElementBy)
{
    try
    {
        return _driver.FindElement(searchElementBy).Displayed;

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WaitUntilElementNotVisible(By.Id("processing"), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use invisibility method, and here is an example usage.

```
final public static boolean waitForElToBeRemove(WebDriver driver, final By by) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(UITestBase.driver,
                DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        boolean present = wait
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by));

        return present;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts()
                .implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says: "An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.". Why would you need `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)` ?

Comment: in this case it was reporting an unnecessary amount of errors in my log. ignoring that exception cleaned the log, but Honestly i switched to doing these checks using all javascript instead. its faster and cleaner. I found this type of check in selenium to not work sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `driver.FindElements` for access to non-existing items.

```
wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(By.Id("processing")).Count == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WaitForElementNotVisible(string id, int seconds)
    {

        try
        {
            var wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));                   
            wait.Until(driver1 => !visibility(id));
            Console.WriteLine("Element is not visible..");
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Element is still visible..");
        }


    }


    bool visibility(string id)
    {
        bool flag;
        try
        {
            flag = driver.FindElement(By.Id(locator)).Displayed;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some context / explanation?

Comment: For instance,your application does have a loading overlay while processing a request or downloading a document or something.You want to wait till the overlay is disappeared.You can use the above method.parameter "id" can be used to provide the web element name and "seconds" to set how long the script should wait before it mark the test as failed .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own ExpectedCondition, just revert visible to **not visible**.

Here is how to do it in python:

```python
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import _element_if_visible

class invisibility_of(object):

    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, ignored):
        return not _element_if_visible(self.element)
```

and how to use it:

```python
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(invisibility_of(elem))
```

Comment: works perfect, for python! c# is another thing, though, it seems. the concept remains, iknow...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but since I was searching for a solution to this, I thought I'd add my thoughts.

The answer given above should work if you set the IgnoreExceptionTypes property:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes = new[] { typeof(NoSuchElementException) }
wait Until(driver => !driver.FindElement(By.Id("processing")).Displayed);
```

Answer (score -17):

In the code below which is used to stop the driver for couple of seconds

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

Comment: Don't ever use Thread.Sleep() for any dynamic situation. There aren't any Best Practices, but this is as close to a Worst Practice as possible. Instead, look to the dynamic conditional WebDriverWait examples shown elsewhere in this post.