# How to wait for WebElement on a web page, which appers sometimes in random places while test execution?

Tags: java, selenium, dom, junit, webdriverwait

I wrote an automated selenium based tests for a web application and they run perfectly with fast internet connection, but unpredictable behavior with less good connection.

Web application was build so, that if duration of response on a request< of some action at the web page, is bigger than 250ms, then appers loader-wrapper element, that prevents any kind of action from user, until response ends. Loader-wrapper can apper at any request in any place of test execution, so i cant use explicit waits of selenium, because i dont know when and where it will appear. As a result i receive an exception:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (411, 675). Other element would receive the click:(.show-component .loader-wrapper)
```

Is there any way to set a "global wait", which will stop test execution if loader-wrapper appered and will wait until it ends, and then test execution will continue? Or any another idea.

Comment: still solving this problem. i will post when finally find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of like your idea of the annotation, but not sure how to implement it.

Another possible approach is to write your own ExpectedCondition "loaderWrapperDisappeared" (or something like that), which would wait for the loader wrapper to be gone, and return the target WebElement so that you could chain a click to it.

You would then use it like this;

```
(new WebDriverWait(targetWebElement, 50))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.loaderWrapperDisappeared(By.id("your div id"))).click();
```

(pardon the syntax it that's wrong...I haven't written java in a few years)

Comment: the main problem of any ExpectedCondition based waits(as i understand it) is that they should be declared in particular places. In my case, i dont know which one WebElement will cause an exception.

Comment: So, all of your targetWebElement.click() calls would instead do the above, where the first arg for WebDriverWait() is not the driver, but the targetWebElement. Yes, it would be a pain, and worthwhile wrapping into some other custom class, but that totally depends on how your automation framework is set up.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I don't think you need to write your own `ExpectedCondition` just use `invisibilityOfElementLocated`... but this is a good answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

In case of web driver, you can have to use like this.

```
WebElement webElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 50))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("your div id")));
```

Here 50 refers to 50 seconds.

For more details, refer below the link.
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#WebDriverWait-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver-long-

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. Your advice is to set explicit wait on web element? If yes, then it can't help me. Because each time this exeption appears in different places(clicking on different WebElements). I can't set waits on every webelement.

Comment: Actually, this is how selenium works because in case of dynamic <div>, some will appear quickly and some may take some more time depending upon the response time. You can only make the time in seconds globally. It has to be done for each id.

Comment: I am exploring for some kind of wait, that, maybe, declared, in @Before annotation of Junit, and awaits only for specific exception with specific context. And if exception is thrown on clicking at some webelement, and exception mathes the rules, then it handle it, waits and repeating this click for 2-4 with pulling interval 500ms

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for [`invisibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

You can add it as a decorator to your steps...

Hope this helps!

Comment: invisibilityOfElementLocated would solve my problem if i knew the webelement, what would cause an exception. i'am not that strong in programming. What did you meant by:
You can add it as a decorator to your steps

Comment: a decorator is basically a way to wrap a function with another function... I use it in Python all the time... not sure how to do it in java...

Comment: yet to your point, you need to know the element of loading... that is the only way to wait for it to disappear

Comment: here is an example for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25240959/8179099

Comment: but this method means, i should use it in every place, where it can happen.
In my case it is about 100 tests and lots of webelements. This unsuitable to me.

Comment: @DaniilUstimenko you can customize your webDriver by inhereting from webDriver and overide all the metuods you need it for and just add the WebDriverWait before the action you intend to take!